# SVG chart scraping by collecting data points on the interactive chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

Hi i am trying to scrape data points from the attached html. I need the dots for the svg chart for scraping the content. I trid like below-

```
dots_css = "div#MBcharts-0.MBcharts-container svg g.MBcharts-grid path"
dots_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(dots_css)
```

I get the data points But the problem is there are two elements with same class names and no id (as shown in the screenshot for "g.MBcharts-grid". 
Though i only need the data points from path from the first occurrence.
Using Python and selenium for webscraping[image]

Comment: please use the snippet tool  via [edit] to share HTML so we can copy paste to test.

Comment: @QHarr sure will keep that in mind here on

Answer (score 1):

If you need the first match of the CSS selector, you could just switch to `.find_element_by_css_selector()` (no `s` after `element`):

```
desired_path = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(dots_css)
```

Or, the [`first-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) would also do the job as the matching elements are siblings:

```
dots_css = "div#MBcharts-0.MBcharts-container svg g.MBcharts-grid:first-child path"
dots_list = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(dots_css)
```

Comment: all the data points in the html content of path are being used to fetch the values by hovering action. If i keep it as .find_element_by_css_selector() i get an error TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len().
Also if i use the first-child method i get Found 0 data points when i
 print("Found {0} data points".format(len(dots_list)))